# Cant get values from object

Tags: javascript, object

I know how that stupid, but i dont understand this simple things.
I have Object, i need get from object **names**. But don't understand how to get access to inner values.
[image: My object]

I try:

```
data['name']
data[0]
data[0].name
```

Every time i get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property

Thanks anyway.

**Upd1:**

Then i try:

> data.constructor

i get this:

```
Cannot read property 'constructor' of null
```

I get data from ajax, from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40142214/dont-understand-state-in-react-js)
When i try:

> JSON.parse(data)

I get:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1(…)

That raw data when i get this from server:

> {"genres":[{"id":28,"name":"Action"},{"id":12,"name":"Adventure"},{"id":16,"name":"Animation"},{"id":35,"name":"Comedy"},{"id":80,"name":"Crime"},{"id":99,"name":"Documentary"},{"id":18,"name":"Drama"},{"id":10751,"name":"Family"},{"id":14,"name":"Fantasy"},{"id":36,"name":"History"},{"id":27,"name":"Horror"},{"id":10402,"name":"Music"},{"id":9648,"name":"Mystery"},{"id":10749,"name":"Romance"},{"id":878,"name":"Science
>   Fiction"},{"id":10770,"name":"TV
>   Movie"},{"id":53,"name":"Thriller"},{"id":10752,"name":"War"},{"id":37,"name":"Western"}]}

Comment: Hmm, the `data[0].name` should have worked

Comment: what is `data`? console log `data.constructor` to find out and post it here

Comment: How are you getting `data`? Some ajax APIs return a response object, and you have to say `response.data...`

Comment: I think you may have to convert your response to JSON object using JSON.parse(data)

Comment: The object in the screen shot looks strange: there is no `{}` around the objects contained in the indexes of the array. Could you please type in the array (or part of it) in stead of showing it using a picture?

Comment: can you share the json data?

Comment: try without parsing the Json Response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know, why that doesn't work before, but now i get everything what i need. Thanks everybody.

```
import React from 'react';
    import { render } from 'react-dom';
    import 'whatwg-fetch';

    const Genres = React.createClass({
        getInitialState : function() {
                return {
                    data: []
            };
        },
        componentDidMount: function() {
            fetch('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=')
                 .then(function(response) {
                     return response.json()
                 }).then(function(json) {
                     this.setState({data: json.genres})
                        //console.log('parsed json', json.genres)
                 }.bind(this)).catch(function(ex) {
                     console.log('parsing failed', ex)
                 })
         },

        render() {
            var data = this.state.data.map(function(key){
                                    return <li>{ key.name }</li>
                })
            console.log(data)
            return (
                <div>
                    Genres:{data}
                </div>
            )
        }
     })

    export default Genres;
```

Comment: Please remove this as it is not an answer but a response.

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing your other question this is your code I'm assuming.

```js
const Main = React.createClass({
    getInitialState : function() {
    return {
      data: null
    };
 },

 componentDidMount: function() {
     var self = this;
     axios.get('https://api')
         .then(function (response) {
            self.setState({data: response.data})
            console.log(response.data);
         })
         .catch(function (error) {
             console.log(error);
         });
        console.log('mount ' + this.state.data );
},
    render() {
        return (
            <h1>{JSON.stringify(this.state.data)}</h1>
        )
    }
})
export default Main;
```

While you are waiting for the server to come back with the data Main.data equals null. This is why you are getting type of null and if you access data like an array you are getting a type error. You could default Main.data to an empty array while you are waiting for the data to populate.

```
const Main = React.createClass({
    getInitialState : function() {
    return {
      data: []
    };
 },
```

As you are using React you will also need to update the component after the data changes. I would suggest looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20605309/pass-new-server-data-to-react-js-components) question for that.

Comment: Just response from server, dont understand how i cant have access to part of Object. Maybe this problem with axios.

Comment: Yes, i read how to use ajax in react, how update react components, now everything work great. Thanks.